# Best way to use image files with database data in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, photo

I'm new to programming and to Django so forgive me if this is an easily-answerable question but I haven't managed to find any solid answers.

I'm currently working on a tour booking website.  I want to add several images to a tour in the Tour class, so that on the tour detail page the user can scroll through the photos.  I'm referencing this page https://medium.com/ibisdev/upload-multiple-images-to-a-model-with-django-fd00d8551a1c for how to write the model, but this method is for users uploading files, so it doesn't explain how to use ones that I already have. How should I deal with these files?

As the link explains, I'm hoping to use an image album class and then use that album in the Tour class, so that I can use several photos for each tour rather than just one image field.

I've seen that you can put images in the database directly, but it seems like it's not the best solution. Should they be stored in the static folder?  If so, how can they be associated with the correct tour in the Tour class?

If they should be stored in the database, how can I call those images from the database and have them displayed in the html?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `django.db.models.FilField` or `django.db.models.ImageField` in your model to store the file name. The actual file will be saved in your media folder and the associated file name will be saved in your database.

make sure you have `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` declared in your `settings.py` to tell django where user uploads will go and how it will be accessed:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ljdoumas/mysite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in your app models.py you will need something like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Tour(models.Model):
    tour_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

you can also set the parameter `upload_to` in your image field to specify exactly where the files should be uploaded to in your media folder.

if you need more than one image you can create another model for images and use a many-to-many relationship to connect them to your tours

Comment: What code can I use to display those images in HTML?  I've seen other database information accessed with double curly braces, {{ tours.name }} for example, but how do I do the same if I have an image album?  {{ tour.album }}?  I recall trying that and it didn't work

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. You probably want something like `<img src={{tour.tour_image}} />` in your template and in your view you need to pass the tour object as the context. Chck the rendered HTML, if you are getting the image address but the image is not showing, you haven't properly configured static file handling in django. Generally for production it isn't recommended that you serve static files through django. However, for development you can try that.

Comment: One last question--I want to upload multiple images to each tour, instead of giving the tour class an image field attribute, it was recommended to create Album class and an Image class (which has the ImageField attribute). The tour and the image both have an "album = models.foreignkey" attribute to link them to the album, but the image is only linked to the tour through that album.  None of the tutorials I read said how to display the images though.  {{tour.album.image}} wouldn't work since the album doesn't have an "image" attribute, so how can I display those images using this method?

Comment: If you have only one Album per Tour, In your Tour model, you need to have a OneToOne field to the Album model: `album = models.OneToOneField(Album)` Then in your Album model you need to have a ManyToMany field to the Image model: `images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)` Then you can access the images using the default set: `{{tour.album.images.all}}` you probably want to iterate through the images to show the results in your template